# a py-script error stating "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas" despite installing pandas

Tags: python, html, excel, pandas, pyscript

I'm trying to code python scripts into html using 'py-script' to exctract data from excel to a webpage. When I run the following code on python it works

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("forwebsite.xlsx")
print()
```

Moreover,  the 'py-script' works too when I run a "hello world" code on a webpage.
Although when I run the code above inside the html, it states the following error:

"JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 429, in eval_code .run(globals, locals) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 300, in run coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals) File "", line 1, in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' )"

The code I wrote on the webpage is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            test
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
<py-env>
- pandas
- paths:
    - /extractcl.py
    - /forwebsite.xlsx
</py-env>
    </head>
    <body><h1>
        <py-script>
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("forwebsite.xlsx")
print()
    </py-script></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why it states that I have 'no module named pandas' when it is installed and works fine with me. Also, if anyone have a better solution of extracting data from excel cells to a website, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: pandas import in pyscript works for me and it's also listed in [Packages built in Pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/packages-in-pyodide.html). You may need to look into your python environments / installation.

Comment: Double-check the indenting for `<py-env>` dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

`<py-env />` changed to `<py-config />`,

Documentation says you need to put `<py-config />` inside `<body />` tag but doing so gives error on importing package.

resolved the issue by putting

```
<py-config>
packages = ['pandas']
</py-config>
```

inside `<head />` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Do you install `pandas`?

`pip install pandas` - on windows

`pip3 install pandas` - on linux

or try to uninstall and install again

`pip uninstall pandas`

Comment: PyScript runs in the web browser. None of your commands will work for PyScript.